# Force Reload a page before loading when clicked on the link attribute

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, weblogic12c

I have a link on my page which opens up a text file located on the file server. when user clicks on the link it opens up the text file as fetched from the file server but this file gets updated when user refreshes the page. subsequently when user clicks on the same link after refresh to open the file it displays the old file. but when did a ctrl+f5(server cache refresh) on the text file tab it then refreshes and displays the updated file. but end user doesn't do a force refresh.  looking to see if there is any work around in JavaScript to do a force refresh of the text file page before loading.

Comment: You can add a no-cache header for that file on your server. Otherwise you should be fetching via ajax (ir fetch() or axios) not just a link.

Comment: Maybe you could add a random string after the url to your text file. It common just to use http://yourdomain.com/mytextfile.txt?r=47393 where 47393 is a random number, normally it would be time and date..

Answer (score 0):

> I would suggest monitoring the anchor in the URL to avoid a reload,
>   that's pretty much the point of using anchors for control-flow. But
>   still here goes. I'd say the easiest way to force a reload using a
>   simple anchor-link would be to use
>
> ```
> <a href="?dummy=$random#myanchor2"></a>
> ```
>
> where in place of $random insert a random number (assuming "dummy" is
>   not interpreted server side). I'm sure there's a way to reload the
>   page after setting the anchor, but it's probably more difficult then
>   simply reacting to the anchor being set and do the stuff you need at
>   that point.
>
> Then again, if you reload the page this way, you can just put
>   myanchor2 as a query parameter instead, and render your stuff server
>   side.
>
> **Edit** 
>   Note that the link above will reload in all circumstances, if you
>   only need to reload if you're not already on the page, you need to
>   have the dummy variable be more predictable, like so
>
> ```
> <a href="?dummy=myanchor2#myanchor2"></a>
> ```
>
> I would still recommend just monitoring the hash though.